# allocating a specific number of bytes in memory

Tags: c

I have been trying to allocate a memory pool of a specified number of bytes in memory. when I proceeded to test the program, it would only allocate a single byte at a time  for each memory pool.

```
   typedef struct _POOL
{
    int size;
    void* memory;

} Pool;

Pool* allocatePool(int x);
void freePool(Pool* pool);
void store(Pool* pool, int offset, int size, void *object);

int main()
{

    printf("enter the number of bytes you want to allocate//>\n");
    int x;
    int y;
    Pool* p;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("enter the number of bytes you want to allocate//>\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    p=allocatePool(x,y);
    return 0;

}



Pool* allocatePool(int x,int y)
{
    static Pool p;
    static Pool p2;
    p.size = x;
    p2.size=y;
    p.memory = malloc(x);
    p2.memory = malloc(y);
    printf("%p\n", &p);
    printf("%p\n", &p2);
    return &p;//return the adress of the Pool


}
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala even if the variable is defined as `static`?

Comment: Ah sorry didn't see that. Then that is correct. Anyway what is that alloc to `p2`; it certainly cannot be accessed outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pool's can be declared in main and passed to the allocatePoll function along with the amount requested and then returned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _POOL
{
    size_t size;
    void* memory;
} Pool;

Pool allocatePool(Pool in, int x);
Pool freePool(Pool in);

int main()
{
    size_t x = 0;
    size_t y = 0;
    Pool p = { 0, NULL};
    Pool p2 = { 0, NULL};

    printf("enter the number of bytes you want to allocate//>\n");
    scanf ( "%zu", &x);
    p=allocatePool(p,x);
    printf("%p\n", p.memory);
    printf("enter the number of bytes you want to allocate//>\n");
    scanf("%zu", &y);
    p2=allocatePool(p2,y);
    printf("%p\n", p2.memory);

    p = freePool ( p);
    p2 = freePool ( p2);
    return 0;
}

Pool freePool(Pool in)
{
    free ( in.memory);
    in.memory = NULL;
    in.size = 0;
    return in;
}

Pool allocatePool(Pool in,size_t amount)
{
    in.size = amount;
    if ( ( in.memory = malloc(amount)) == NULL && amount != 0) {
        printf ( "Could not allocate memory\n");
        in.size = 0;
        return in;
    }
    printf("%p\n", in.memory);
    return in;//return Pool
}
```